# Гарантированная передача UDP пакетов

Tags: c, сокет, udp, openvpn

UDP это протокол, который не поддерживает постоянные соединения и не обеспечивает гарантированной доставки пакетов.

Вопрос, а как тогда работает OpenVPN по UDP протоколу? Как до клиента доходят какие-то пакеты от сервера, если клиент находится за NAT? Клиент не может открыть на прослушивание порт и сервер не может использовать постоянное соединение (из-за его отсутствия в UDP).

Если можно привести минимальный пример клиент-серверного приложения на UDP протоколе с возможностью отправки данных с сервера

Comment: От TCP ни чем не отличается. Когда клиент отправляет запрос на сервер NAT запоминает его ip-порт и если ответ от сервера поступит достаточно быстро (например в linux по умолчанию 30 секунд), то NAT отлично передаст пакет через себя. После того как ответный пакет прошел NAT может увеличить время на забывание сессии (в linux до 120 секунд) и пара порт-ip будет рабочей это время.

Comment: @Mike хорошо, а как мне на клиенте определить какой порт слушать? Вернее с какого порта функция `sendto` отправила пакет? И где гарантия того, что при повторном вызове `sendto` второй пакет уйдет с того же порта?

Comment: Но разные NAT по разному работают с тем что запоминают. Некоторые позволяют любым ip слать на сохраненную пару ip-порт, другие только тем кому слали пакеты. Вообще UDP активно используется как раз для "пробивки" NAT для установления соединений точка-точка между двумя клиентами, находящимися на NAT (с использованием сервера для затравки) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

Comment: @Mike Спасибо. Идея вроде ясна. Буду пробовать реализовать в коде. А система подтверждений используется ручная? Типа id пакета и таймаут ожидания?

Comment: Ну да. И не обязательно подтверждать каждый пакет. можно схему на подобии TCP сделать. Можно еще десятками других способов. И вообще есть масса приложений, где потеря пары пакетов не важна

Comment: @Mike "От TCP ни чем не отличается" - на самом деле - сильно отличается. Например, в TCP данные можно рассматривать как непрерывный поток. TCP поддерживает сегментацию больших пакетов и упаковку маленьких...